# Read script inserted before

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, navigation

I have a html with a menu, that doesnt redirect to other page when the user chooses an option in the menu, the script inserts the target html inside a section on the main page. But i want to manipulate that inserted html, but all the 's that i use only seems to read the information on the main html. How could i manipulate the html inserted?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="background">

<head>
    <title>METRO PROJECT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="">
                <a href="https://google.com.br"><img src="images/metroLogo.png" width=9%></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href mnav="index.html"><b>HOME</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href mnav="consulta.html"><b>CONSULTA</b></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href mnav="mapa.html"><b>MAPA</b></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="teste">
        <!-- <div class ="white-box">   -->
    </section>

    </div>
    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll( '[mnav]' ).forEach( link => {
            const conteudo = document.getElementById( 'teste' )

            link.onclick = function ( e ) {
                e.preventDefault()
                fetch( link.getAttribute( 'mnav' ) )
                    .then( resp => resp.text() )
                    .then( html => conteudo.innerHTML = html )
            }
        } )


        //HERE I WANT TO MANIPULATE THE SCRIPT THAT IS INSERTED (A FORM)

        const submit = document.querySelector( '[mSubmit' )
        submit.onclick = function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault()
            const form = e.target.parentNode
            const formData = new FormData( form )
            const hora = formData.get( 'horas' )
            const minuto = formData.get( 'minutos' )
            console.log( hora )
            console.log( minuto )
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the code that does the navigation without redirecting the page. i want to manipulate the html inserted but nothing works.

Comment: We need to see HTML and any CSS associated with it. This script is inserting dynamic HTML somewhere in the DOM, but without what you're working with in the DOM... I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Just updated the code, can you check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run all the code for the elements that you  insert to the dom after you insert the elements in the fetch function.

```
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll( '[mnav]' ).forEach( link => {
        const conteudo = document.getElementById( 'teste' )

        link.onclick = function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault()
            fetch( link.getAttribute( 'mnav' ) )
                .then( resp => resp.text() )
                .then( html => conteudo.innerHTML = html )
                .then(() => {
                             const submit = document.querySelector( '[mSubmit' )
                             submit.onclick = function ( e ) {
                             e.preventDefault()
                             const form = e.target.parentNode
                             const formData = new FormData( form )
                             const hora = formData.get( 'horas' )
                             const minuto = formData.get( 'minutos' )
                             console.log( hora )
                             console.log( minuto )
                             }
                })
        }
    } )


    //HERE I WANT TO MANIPULATE THE SCRIPT THAT IS INSERTED (A FORM)



</script>
```